# How to reduce the lag of jumping between pages(fragment/activity)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a FragmentA(*with Recyclerview*) and a FragmentB(*item*). When I click in A to jump to B, the page lags a bit, maybe I updated the content in the main thread? But I don't seem to be doing that.

In FragmentB, I have some text and 3 Recyclerview, maybe the recyclerview cause the lag?
[image]

May be I need to load the data after the transition animation is complete? How to finish it?

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of many things. Check if you are using a large image size that can use more power and time to render. Try to move your long operations into coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

As your layouts has one image, 3 recycler view & other stuff there is many cases for layout lagging.

1. May the image you are loading is larger. (Try: load it with Glide or other image loading libraries)

2.May your 3 recycler listing has large number of items & you are loading them immediately after creating your fragment view. (Try: put them into the runnanble & load them after some delay of a time)